# Outer/Inner join in excel

Tags: excel

I have two Microsoft Excel 2010 files named `2011.xls` and `2012.xls` which contain tables of student information.

How can I do an outer/inner join of these two tables on one column, say `student name`?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet and I waiting for a solution from someone.

Comment: You can access excel files as datasources in msquery but you have to try

Comment: Excel is not a database program, it is a spreadsheet program. Try MSAccess which is more likely to support relational operations such as join.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at using the Excel function VLOOKUP. See Excel Help for VLOOKUP

Comment: Thank you very much. VLOOKUP worked like a miracle. You made my day!

Answer (score 1):

For an inner join, VLOOKUP is the best / fastest tool. For an outer join, you can use a macro like [this one](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/simulate-an-outer-join-with-excel/) in my blog.

Answer (score 0):

Two files means two databases, and the OLEDB Driver used to connect to Excel dont support multiple databases. You need to put your worksheets together in one workbook, and after this, use this procedure:

http://www.tomasvasquez.com.br/blog/microsoft-office/videos-unindo-dados-de-duas-ou-mais-planilhas-no-excel

The videos are in portuguese language, but its possible to get the idea.

I hope it helps

Comment: I will try to get as much as I can from this video. But I am surprised there is no much information out there for joining excel tables.

Comment: The concept in the video is you cant have JOIN ou UNION bettwen two tables (worksheets) in two different databases (workbooks). You must merge the worksheets in the same workbook to use the JOIN statement. This is a limitation about Excel files using OLEDB provider.